# Powershell And SQL With Multiple NotLike Filters For Database Names

Tags: sql, powershell

I'm querying a system database on multiple servers with PowerShell. The original SQL query has several "AND name NOT LIKE" in the WHERE clause. I can do this in PowerShell with -NotLike, but the number of "AND name NOT LIKE" is fairly long. Is there any way to make the "AND name NOT LIKE" list simpler in PowerShell?

SQL AND name NOT LIKE

```
AND name NOT LIKE 'DBA%'
AND name NOT LIKE 'DB_LOS%'
AND name NOT LIKE 'JIRA%'
AND name NOT LIKE 'Report%'
AND name NOT LIKE 'AdventureWorks%'
AND name NOT LIKE '%APM%'
AND name NOT LIKE '%AZEU%'
AND name NOT LIKE '%TM1%'
AND name NOT LIKE '%Utility%'
AND name NOT LIKE '%detail_epro%'
AND name NOT LIKE '%config_epro%'
AND name NOT LIKE '%summary_epro%'
AND name NOT LIKE '%lookup%'
AND name NOT LIKE '%meldb%'
AND name NOT LIKE '%Sandbox%'
AND name NOT LIKE '%Scribe%'
AND name NOT LIKE '%Stage%'
AND name NOT LIKE '%Staging%'
AND name NOT LIKE '%STG%'
AND name NOT LIKE '%SSRS%'
AND name NOT LIKE '%snapshot%'
```

PowerShell

```
Get-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance DBServer | Where-Object {$_.name -notlike "db_los*" -and $_.name -notlike "DBA*"} | Select-Object name, status
```

Eventually this will be automated to go across several servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using multiple `-notlike` operators, you can also put all strings to not like in a pipe `|` separated string and use the regex `-notmatch` operator like this:

```
# create a regex string using the OR character as separator

# this line anchors the names at the beginning of the line
$excluded = '^(?:db_los|DBA|JIRA|Report|AdventureWorks)' 
# append the names that may occur anywhere in the line
$excluded += '|APM|AZEU|TM1|Utility|detail_epro|config_epro|summary_epro|lookup|meldb|Sandbox|Scribe|Stage|Staging|STG|SSRS|snapshot'
```

Then use this like:

```
Get-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance DBServer | 
    Where-Object {$_.name -notmatch $excluded} |
    Select-Object name, status
```

The above matches Case-Insensitive. If you need case-sensitivity, replace `-notmatch` with `-cnotmatch`

Regex details:

> ```
>                                Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
>    ^                           Assert position at the beginning of the string
>    (?:                         Match the regular expression below
>                                Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
>          db_los                Match the characters “db_los” literally
>       |                        Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
>          DBA                   Match the characters “DBA” literally
>       |                        Or match regular expression number 3 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
>          JIRA                  Match the characters “JIRA” literally
>       |                        Or match regular expression number 4 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
>          Report                Match the characters “Report” literally
>       |                        Or match regular expression number 5 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
>          AdventureWorks        Match the characters “AdventureWorks” literally
>    )                        
> |                              Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
>    APM                         Match the characters “APM” literally
> |                              Or match regular expression number 3 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
>    AZEU                        Match the characters “AZEU” literally
> |                              Or match regular expression number 4 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
>    TM1                         Match the characters “TM1” literally
> |                              Or match regular expression number 5 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
>    Utility                     Match the characters “Utility” literally
> |                              Or match regular expression number 6 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
>    detail_epro                 Match the characters “detail_epro” literally
> |                              Or match regular expression number 7 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
>    config_epro                 Match the characters “config_epro” literally
> |                              Or match regular expression number 8 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
>    summary_epro                Match the characters “summary_epro” literally
> |                              Or match regular expression number 9 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
>    lookup                      Match the characters “lookup” literally
> |                              Or match regular expression number 10 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
>    meldb                       Match the characters “meldb” literally
> |                              Or match regular expression number 11 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
>    Sandbox                     Match the characters “Sandbox” literally
> |                              Or match regular expression number 12 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
>    Scribe                      Match the characters “Scribe” literally
> |                              Or match regular expression number 13 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
>    Stage                       Match the characters “Stage” literally
> |                              Or match regular expression number 14 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
>    Staging                     Match the characters “Staging” literally
> |                              Or match regular expression number 15 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
>    STG                         Match the characters “STG” literally
> |                              Or match regular expression number 16 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
>    SSRS                        Match the characters “SSRS” literally
> |                              Or match regular expression number 17 below (the entire match attempt fails if this one fails to match)
>    snapshot                    Match the characters “snapshot” literally
> ```